# Removing sort arrows from AdvancedDataGridColumn Header

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, user-interface, flex4

I am doing this simple project using Flex 4 SDK and I got stuck with this simple problem: I have turned sortable property for AdvancedDataGridColumn to false, but the column header is still rendered as:
[image]

As You can see, my label for this header is "06", but the column header is divided and it keeps the place for sort arrow.

How can I change this? I would like my column header to contain only my label.

I know that most probably I need to do some magic with AdvancedDataGridHeaderRenderer but I just started learning Flex and would like to receive some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following property to the AdvancedDataGrid itself:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid sortExpertMode="true"/>
```

That will get rid of the annoying extra space for the arrows. An arrow will still show up when you click a column header for sorting, but it will be smaller and less obtrusive. It won't reserve space for itself in the header.

Answer (score 2):

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid sortExpertMode="true">        
<mx:columns>
    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn sortable="false" />
```